# Does Jetbrains Appcode still work after upgrading to the Xcode 4.2 beta release?

Tags: ios, xcode, appcode

Does Jetbrains AppCode still work after upgrading to the Xcode 4.2 beta release?

https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think so, but *you definitely should stay on non beta Xcode*, i.e. 4.0.2 for iOS development.

**You won't be able to submit apps to AppStore with 4.2.** (Forget Lion!)

Also, I "played" with Xcode 4.2 for few hours, until I found a breaking bug in CoreData in iOS5... I think iOS5 is not stable enough yet to make Xcode 4.2 a serious development env.
Too bad Xcode 4.2 is really more fast & stable.

So here is my suggestion (that's what I do) :

1. Install Xcode 4.0.2 in `/Developer`
2. Install Xcode 4.2 in `/Xcode42` (or whatever)
3. Make sure to run `xcode-select /Developer` or AppCode will use Xcode 4.2 for building and running apps.

Note: Before someone reports this, no subject under NDA has been discussed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does. It doesn't support new language features yet (some red code in editor) but will do so in a couple of weeks.

Comment: Thanks Maxim, love your work at JetBrains - looking forward to buying AppCode!